# Spring Integration Webservice Gateway: add http Headers as SOAP Headers

Tags: spring-integration, saaj

I am trying to write configure a Spring Inbound Webservice Gateway, which should take a complete SOAP Message and then delegate it to another SOAP Provider (neccessary for security reasons).
Should look like
(1) Application -> (2) SOAP Provicer and Client for (THIS is my Part / Configuration) -> (3) Second SOAP Provider  -> (4) Services

What I have done so far for issue (2):

1) web.xml

```
MessageDispatcherServlet with Mapping:
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/appservices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

2) Configuration with an Endpoint-Mapping

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
    <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="ws-in-gw"/>
</bean>
```

3) Configuration of Spring Integration inbound-gateway and outbound-gateway

```
<!-- My Providing Part -->
<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="ws-in-gw" 
    request-channel="in" 
    reply-channel="out" 
    mapped-request-headers="*" />

<int:channel id="in" />

<int:channel id="out" />

<!-- My Client Part -->
<int-ws:outbound-gateway
    id="ws-out-gw-status"
    request-channel="in-status"
    reply-channel="out-status"
    uri="http://${delegationServer}/${delegation.contextroot}/soap/AnotherService"
</int-ws:outbound-gateway>
```

Everything works fine right now, but now I have to add some HTTP header (added to the request by the firewall on the way from 1 to 2) to the SOAP Message in process 2

This is the SOAP Message for my test:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:stat="http://status.service.promakler.provinzial.com/">

    <soapenv:Body>
        <stat:getStatus/>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I think I have to set the extract-payload attribute of the inbound gateway to false, but this way I get an exception. I think I have to write an Marshaller/Unmarshaller,
but I don't know how to do this. The result should be a SaajSoapMessage I think. Any ideas?

Regards
 Timo

Comment: Please, be more specific. Do you want to transfer incoming HTTP headers to that external request as HTTP headers, too, or do you want to populate them as `<soapenv:Header>` ?

Comment: Sorry... I want to put them as soapenv:Headers

Comment: Sorry, for the delay. Try to follow with recommendation from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476246/passing-http-headers-dynamically-using-spring-integration/28476898#28476898